# PHP mysql field 1 plus field 2 * 5 wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

I have a table with 4 fields in MySQL. 1 is product price cost 2 is price we sell 3 is stock of products 4 is earning by unit.

Example

Cost of product for us 100,
Selling price to customers is 120, 
Stock is 10
The follow code calculate the earnings by unit

```
<?php echo number_format($product['sellingprice'] - $product['cost'],0,',','.'); ?>
```

And it works fine it shows that the earnings we make by selling 1 unit is 20

now the problem, I need to calculate how much is the total earning by getting the earning for unit and multiplicate by stock ( 20 * 10 = 200 )

I am trying to do with the follow code

```
<?php echo number_format($product['sellingprice'] - $product['cost'] *  $product['stock'],0,',','.'); ?>
```

But the result I get is wrong even with minus symbol like -23.454

Any ideas?

Comment: PEMDAS: parenthesis, exponents, multiplication, division, addition, subtraction.

Comment: Can you give me an example with number format please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply earning per unit (`($product['sellingprice'] - $product['cost'])`) by the amount of stock (`$product['stock']`):

```
<?php echo number_format(($product['sellingprice'] - $product['cost']) *  $product['stock'],0,',','.'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic math 101: You forgot to use brackets:

```
$sell = 20;
$cost = 10;
$stock = 50;

$result1 = $sell - $cost * $stock;   -> 20 - (10 * 50) -> 20 - 500 -> -480
$result2 = ($sell - $cost) * $stock; -> (20 - 10) * 50 -> 10 * 50 -> 500
```

Never forget the BEDMAS mnemonic: brackets, exponents, division, multiplication, addition subtraction.

Comment: Is there a way simpler way? I don´t understand your solution I am a newbie in PHP

Comment: put brackets into your math....

Comment: can you give me an example with number format please?

Comment: I'll upvote this tonight, because you've laid it out so well. I'm plum out of votes already - *grin*